# Why is this URL PArameter not hiding this div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am attempting to animate a page div, if the URL has "?success=true" attached.

I have tried multiple methods, to no avail (this is currently placed in the footer).

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        if (getParameterByName("success") == "true") 
            $("#success-cover").hide(); 
        });
</script>
```

And I am using it to affect:

```
<div id="success-cover" class="success-cover">
 <div class="success" id="success"><img class="success-logo" src="images/logo-small-new.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: No server side script to capture the $_GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got syntax errors in your if statement:

```
    if (getParameterByName("success") == "true") {
        $("#success-cover").hide(); 
    }
```

Comment: ROOKIE. ERROR.

THANK YOU.